# How to append <script> that will be executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kxALH/2/) :

```
<a href="#" id="showAlert">Click me</a>
<div id="pasteContent"></div>
​
var elemFunc = '<script>alert("myString");</script>';

$("#showAlert").click(function () {
    $("#pasteContent").html(elemFunc);
});
​
```

What I'd like to do is to append the string alert(myString); (which is a script) that must be executed... how can I do? Is it not correct?

Comment: Why don't you just execute your script from inside the click handler?

Comment: For many motivations... hard to explain right now...

Comment: Am I just going crazy, or has nobody noticed that the general way it's presented above (ie. aside from any other code issues) will never work because the script that's appending the `<script>` is not itself enclosed in `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a backslash before `/` in `</script>`: http://jsfiddle.net/kxALH/3/
Your code failed, because `</script>` is considered as a close tag for your fiddle script. As a result, your first fiddle looked somewhat weird.

Note: If you want to execute an arbitrary string of code, [`$.globalEval('alert("myString")');`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) may suit better.

Comment: @JKirchartz His current method is similar to `jQuery.globalEval`, but not neat. He hasn't given background details on his use case, but I assume that he surely needs it (see [his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432340/how-to-append-script-that-will-be-executed/9432383#comment11926622_9432340) at the OP).

Answer (score 0):

try it whit a jquery script object like this

```
var elemFunc = $('<script>')
    .attr('type', 'text/javascript')
    .html('alert("myString");');

$("#showAlert").click(function () {
    $("#pasteContent").append(elemFunc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elemFunc = '<script>alert("myString");</' + 'script>';
```

If you have your JS inside your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
$("head").append(s);
```

Note that the script will load and you can access the variables inside it, but you wouldn't see the actual  tag in the DOM.

Comment: I do see my DOM being updated with `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somedomain.com/somescript"></script>`, but the script won;t be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you're going equates to an `eval`, and eval IS evil, You can use an external script and `$.getScript()`, to load it via ajax...

```
$.getScript("http://scriptURL.com/script.js", function(){ init(); });
```